# How to cast inside a case statement in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I'm using Hive to write a simple case statement but when I try casting a string class as int in a case statement it just keeps spinning for minutes. Can someone assist with this?

```
select case when cast(RISK_CLASS as int) = 5 THEN 'HIGH' ELSE 'TEST' END as test from student.history limit 10
```

Comment: Hive probably needs to process all the data to run the query.  I imagine `select risk_class from student.history limit 10` would also take time.

Comment: I've tried to limit 10 and the same thing happens. I thought it was something wrong with my query but it looks fine.

Comment: can you run for 1 student ? Is there partition like date - can you check and apply filter accordingly?

Comment: I had to specify some columns in the where clause

Comment: Guess limit 10 will work on the reducer lever when it has processed all the records in mapper and reducers. You need to narrow down your data at mapper level by adding where clause on some partition keys